YouTube Data API insert.comment moderation
I have made a code to insert.comment using the OAuth2.0 refresh tokens stored in a secure file using the Youtube Data API.
after 10 days, some moderation might have started and I am not able to see the reflections of the insert comment in the comment section.
I see an increase in number of total comments but the comment is not seen, I have made sure that it was not moderated by our own channel.
Main changes from development to production:
Server is G-cloud now instead of local.
The refresh tokens were Authenticated ~2 months ago.
Please advice on what should be done.
I tried a lot of post tries and I have observed:
The total comments for the video increase for a moment and as I refresh the comment goes off, whether it is a new comment or older comment
but this does not happen if try it locally for the older comments, I haven't tried it to the newer comments in the prod DB.
Older comment: close to the day of OAuth2.0 authentication to get refresh tokens.
Newer comment: are newer comments that are not updated in the dev DB

How do you ensure that but the comment is not seen?

After is sent the insert request I constantly refreshed the page and checked the comments section there were 2 cases:

As I refresh the number of comments increased by one as it should but the reply was never posted, nor was it moderated by the channel.
sometimes after this the number of comments goes back to the original like : +1 for 2-3 refreshes and goes back to base number of comments before post -1 again.


Have you paid attention to select on the YouTube UI Sort by Newest first instead of Top comments?

Yes,
I haven't made that kinds of errors, the information I gave are true and tested.
